# Looking for clarity on Thread.sleep() method

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, thread-sleep

Thread.sleep() method puts the thread that is running it to sleep.
thread.sleep() statement in the below code will be run by main thread, 'thread' in the below code is an user defined thread. Why is the main thread is sleeping when called on the reference of user defined thread.

```
public class ThreadDemo {

    public static Thread t1 = null;
    public static Thread t2 = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        System.out.println("start of main function, Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        t1 = Thread.currentThread(); //main thread
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        t2 = thread;
        thread.start();

        System.out.println("Before sleep in main method : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("After sleep in main method : "+System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println("In main method, Thread : "+t1.getName()+" ,In state: "+t1.getState());
        System.out.println("In main method, Thread : "+t2.getName()+" ,In state: "+t2.getState());

        System.out.println("Is thread, "+thread.getName() + " alive : "+ thread.isAlive());

        System.out.println("end of main function, Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static class MyThread extends Thread{
        int sum = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("In run method, Thread : "+t1.getName()+" ,In state: "+t1.getState());
            System.out.println("In run method, Thread : "+t2.getName()+" ,In state: "+t2.getState());
            System.out.println("start of run method, Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
                sum += i;
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("After sleep in run method : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("end of run method, "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() +", returns : "+sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
start of main function, Thread : main
Before sleep in main method : 1701105524066
In run method, Thread : main ,In state: TIMED_WAITING
In run method, Thread : Thread-0 ,In state: RUNNABLE
start of run method, Thread : Thread-0
After sleep in main method : 1701105525070
In main method, Thread : main ,In state: RUNNABLE
In main method, Thread : Thread-0 ,In state: TIMED_WAITING
Is thread, Thread-0 alive : true
end of main function, Thread : main
After sleep in run method : 1701105534071
end of run method, Thread-0, returns : 49995000
```

I don't understand how main thread is sleeping when called on the reference of user defined thread.

Comment: What kind of error were you expecting, and why?

Comment: Tip: Replace `System.currentTimeMillis()` with `java.time.Instant.now()`.

Comment: Why would `Thread#sleep` throw an error? A non-daemon `Thread` is allowed to continue running even when the main thread completes, as the jvm will not shutdown until all non-daemon threads complete (Which they are by default, unless you are currently a daemon thread. The main thread is non-daemon). What you're seeing here is normal, your main thread completes first, then the second thread completes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can thread run after main method closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146899/how-can-thread-run-after-main-method-closes)

Comment: Nothing is calling interrupt on the thread. Here is an answer demonstrating thread interruption https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915306/217324

Comment: @BasilBourque My confusion is how thread.sleep() puts main thread to sleep when 'thread' here is a reference of user defined thread.

Comment: Sleep is a static method. Java doesnt care what instance you call it on.

Comment: You can't force another thread to sleep.

Comment: Don't think of `thread.sleep(n)` as putting _any_ thread to sleep. What `thread.sleep(1000)` does in your program is the same as what `Thread.sleep(1000)` would do. And what `Thread.sleep(1000)` does is _nothing._ It does nothing for 1000 milliseconds,\* and then it returns. \[* Actually, for _at least_ 1000 milliseconds. It's allowed to take a tiny bit longer than the time you specify, but it is not allowed to take any less time.]

Comment: You said it yourself. It puts the thread *that is running it* to sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting a thread put another thread to sleep would be a security risk so it is not allowed. `Thread.sleep` is a static method that puts the current thread to sleep.

One of the more confusing features of the Java language is that you're allowed to call static methods on object instances as if they were instance methods. The actual instance is ignored (it can even be null), the type of the variable is used to figure out what class to call the method on. But that can leave the user thinking they are doing something with a particular instance that they aren't.

Comment: Admittedly `someThread.sleep(...)` is like a witch accidentally drinking her own potions.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the main thread is sleeping when called on the reference of user defined thread.

If we look at the [`Thread` class source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) we see:

> ```
> public static native void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException;
> ```

This is a `static` method so should be called as `Thread.sleep(...)` and not on an instance of `Thread`.  Calling it as `thread.sleep(...)` is a an anti-pattern.  You think you are affecting the `thread` instance but in reality the caller is the one that is sleeping.  Looking at the javadocs of this method it confirms this:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

In [Eclipse (a free IDE)](https://www.eclipse.org/), when I try to use `sleep()` with an instance variable I get a warning:

[image]

Paying attention to these sorts of warnings will help.